# How to make a Relationship in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

i am begginer of springboot. how to make the relationship between employee and task.how to make the relationship this is one to one relationship.what i tried so far i attached below.

after made the relation and add the data i got the error was

```
2023-03-28 13:24:46.853  WARN 8676 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.SpingProject.Entity.Employee` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.SpingProject.Entity.Employee` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2')<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.example.SpingProject.DTO.TaskSaveDTO["employee"])]
```

**task**

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="task")
    public class Task {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "task_id", length = 50)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int taskid;
    
        @Column(name = "task_name", length = 50)
        private String taskname;
    
        @Column(name = "description", length = 80)
        private String description;
    
        @OneToOne
        private Employee employee;
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeid;

    @Column(name = "employee_name", length = 50)
    private String employeename;

    @Column(name = "employee_address", length = 80)
    private String employeeaddress;

    @Column(name = "employee_mobile", length = 80)
    private  int mobile;
```

**TaskServiceIMPL.java**

```
 public String addTask(TaskSaveDTO taskSaveDTO) {

        Task task = new Task(
                taskSaveDTO.getTaskname(),
                taskSaveDTO.getDescription(),
                taskSaveDTO.getEmployee()
        );

        taskRepo.save(task);
        return task.getTaskname();

    }
```

Comment: From the message it seems that  `taskSaveDTO.getEmployee()` returns just the string `2` instead of one `Employee` object.

Comment: how to retur two object